# Why JBoss not deploy static css,js files in a war(EAR project)

Tags: jsf, deployment, jboss, wildfly, ear

I have an EAR project with core,db, and web modules. I want to modify my css files, i do it, but when i see in browser it loads, but not refreshing. I tried with a style tag, but same result. Any Jboss coniguration, or something else?

Comment: To avoid the obvious (particularly when you're actually new to web development and somehow missed the basics), is the server (re)published (and thus in sync with project)? And, did you in the browser try a forced reload or a new incognito window in order to bypass browser cache?

Comment: Where do your CSS files exist? How are you deploying your application?